# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when installing debug apk (Edit: 22.10.2019 Installing APP hangs on 8.1 Device SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

I have a problem installing debug apk, and no problem if I try to install signed apk. (on android 8.0). I can work around this, by removing a lib folder that contains .sh .jar (that contains nothing special) and .ps1 files in one of my libraries.

I really want to know, how signing the APK file solves this issue.
I fail to see what ABIs have to do with those files I have.

Problem is with Android Studio 3.0.1 and 3.1.2 (will test soon with 3.1.3).

Edit: 22.10.2019
Today, after 8 hours of removing and adding parts of a project of mine while dealing with SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE error that gives no important information whatsoever, when the install of my APP hangs, after I got new 8.1 device to develop with, I found out that:

The reason for being stuck on Installing APP is another .jar file, with a lib folder in it, containing similar files.

**The solution was to use "packingOptions" in build.gradle(Module:app) and use exclude 'lib/name' for every file name contained in that lib folder.**

I am not sure how much this is a solution, since it seems like cutting off a limb, instead of healing the wound at first place.

Anyway, if someone has any information to clarify why all of this is happening.

Comment: Interesting..to see that it's working with signed apk. Will update here if I find anything.